# c++ singleton structure queue

Tags: c++, struct, queue

There is a queue  in the singleton variable.

However, when pushing from another class, the push value is not matched and the error continues.

Please.

[singleton header]

```
typedef struct _Hybrid_Message_st
{
   int hy_state;
    std::string hy_msg;
} Hybrid_Message_st;

class Hybrid_Singleton
{
  private:
    static Hybrid_Singleton *instance;
    Hybrid_Singleton(void){}
  public:
    ~Hybrid_Singleton(void){}
    static Hybrid_Singleton* getInstance();
    std::queue<Hybrid_Message_st> hy_queue;
    int count;
 };
```

[singleton source]

```
  Hybrid_Singleton* Hybrid_Singleton::getInstance()
  {
    if(instance == NULL)
    {
        instance = new Hybrid_Singleton;
    }

    return instance;
 }

 Hybrid_Singleton *Hybrid_Singleton::instance = NULL;
```

[Question?]

```
 Hybrid_Message_st ss;
 ss.hy_state = 0;
 ss.hy_msg = "Hellow";
 Hybrid_Singleton::getInstance()->hy_queue.push(ss);
```

[Error]

```
 error: no matching function for call to ‘std::queue<_Hybrid_Message_st>::push(broadcast_server::Hybrid_Message_st&)’
```

Comment: Your code compiles and runs without any issues on MinGW 5.3. Just a comment, the `typedef struct` syntax should not be needed with C++, are there any reason why you are using this syntax

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the type `ss` is a `broadcast_server::Hybrid_Message_st`, while the Singleton is using a `Hybrid_Message_st`. Note the difference in namespace between the types.

It's possible that you are `using broadcast_server` somewhere in your code.

Comment: Thank you.
Include was included twice in the header.